# How can I split up views in Flask into submodules while still using url_for effectively?

Tags: python, flask

Say that I have a flask project organized like this

```
app/
├── __init__.py
└── views.py
```

but that my `views.py` file is starting to have a lot of code in it and could easily be broken up into some conceptually different parts. My first thought would be to break views up into submodules like this

```
app/
├── __init__.py
└── views
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── some_views.py
    └── some_other_views.py
```

When I do this, my routes all work fine but I run into issues when using `url_for`. I would like to be able to do something like `url_for('views.some_views.my_view')` but it only works if I do `url_for('my_view')`. The problem with this is that I have template code that might be rendered from different submodules and it will break depending on the depth.

Is there any way to break the code up like this while still allowing `url_for` to be called using the full path to a view? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/).

Comment: I read about blueprints and they kind of sounded like overkill for this use case but I wasn't 100% sure. I want the views to use the same static folder, use the same template folder, and be under the same url routing prefix... I just want to organize the code more neatly. Are blueprints really necessary in this case?

Comment: The static folder and templates can be the same, but not the URL prefix. If that's a deal breaker, it sounds like you just need to make sure all of your endpoints have unique names. If you're afraid of having two functions called `my_view`, just override the endpoint (e.g., `@app.route('/my_view', endpoint='views_my_view')`).

Comment: I'm interested in why you need this particular project structure and if there isn't some other way to do what you need. Unless you have hundreds on top of hundreds of routes then I think one file should be enough. It's ok to have python files with a lot of code in them. It's not unheard of.

Comment: @dirn Thanks for the info. I think in this case I'll just be careful about the function names but I'll look into blueprints more for future applications.

Comment: @m1yag1 It's just a matter of personal preference. I thought that there might be some configuration option that changed this behavior and if there was then that's what I would have preferred.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the Flask source, it's actually pretty straightforward to monkey patch in whatever behavior you want for how the default endpoints are determined. Flask defines a `flask.helpers._endpoint_from_view_func` which takes a function as an argument and returns the name of the function. This is then used in `flask.app.add_url_rule` to populate the default endpoint if one isn't supplied. I just added

```
import flask
flask.app._endpoint_from_view_func = lambda f: '.'.join(f.__module__.split('.')[1:] + [f.__name__])
```

to my top level `__init__.py` file to customize how the default endpoints are constructed. This lets me use `url_for('views.some_views.my_view')` instead of `url_for('my_view')`, which was my original goal. Personally, I think this allows for saner namespacing when using submodules to organize code.